# Finding matching vector from millions of vectors

Tags: algorithm, vector-search

I have millions of unique 10-dimensional vectors. In these vectors, if a dimension is 0, it means this vector can match any value in this dimension. Now, I have a vector, and I want to find which of these million vectors matches it. No dimension in this vector can be 0. Could you please help me design an algorithm for this?
For example.

```
vectors:
[
  [1, 1, 1, 1, ... 1],
  [2, 2, 0, 2, ... 2],  //In the third dimension any value can be matched
  [3, 0, 3, 3, ... 3],  //In the second dimension any value can be matched
  ...
]

Search:
input vector: [1, 1, 1, 1, ... 1] , output: [1, 1, 1, 1, ... 1]
input vector: [2, 2, 4, 2, ... 2] , output: [2, 2, 0, 2, ... 2]
input vector: [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 10], output: null
```

I tried using the KD-tree, but it doesn't satisfy my particular matching rules (maybe I don't know how to use it).

Any programming language will be OK.

Comment: How many queries do you expect? One, hundreds, millions? What is the range of the values in the vectors?

Comment: @beaker About thousands of queries per second. The value is integer and the range is from -2^31 to 2^31-1

Comment: Only 10 dimensions? Form the 1024 possible answers and check them all (use a hash table to store the vectors).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, only 10 dimensions. I tried using HashMap to store all possible answers of the vectors, but it takes a lot of memory. My program runs on a single machine. I'm trying to strike a balance between memory usage and search speed. So I'm looking for algorithms to solve the problem.

Comment: To be clear, you're only storing the vectors in your list in the hash table, right? Not all of the 2^64^10 *possible* vectors?

Comment: @beaker Yes, only the vectors in my list.

Comment: Okay, well if you can't store your vector list in memory, where are you getting this list?

Comment: "I tried using HashMap to store all possible answers" That's exactly the opposite of what I told you. Use HashMap to store vectors (not possible answers). Generate possible answers from a query, not from the vectors (there are 1024 of them, not billions).

Comment: @beaker My list is from a postgres table. I can store all my vectors in memory, but I can't store all possible cases in my vectors. For example I have 2 million vectors. Storing 2 million vectors in memory is almost hitting the limit, so I can't store (2 ^ 10) * 2000000 possible vectors in memory.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Did you mean store the original vectors and try to traverse as many possible answers as possible when searching? (Up to 1024 queries) This is a good idea to reduce memory by consuming CPU. Thank you. But I'm still curious if there's an algorithm to solve this query problem.

Comment: The 1024 hash tables is a good algorithm. This will run in expected O(1).

Comment: @jptx That's why I asked my question. You only have to store the original vectors, not all possible vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple approach. Memory shouldn't be too bad.

```
def make_trie (vectors):
    trie = {}
    for vector in vectors:
        node = trie
        for i in range(len(vector) - 1, -1, -1):
            if vector[i] not in node:
                node[vector[i]] = {}
            node = node[vector[i]]
    return trie

def search_vector (trie, target, i=None):
    if i is None:
        i = len(target) - 1
    if i == -1:
        yield []
    else:
        if 0 in trie:
            for v in search_vector(trie[0], target, i-1):
                v.append(0)
                yield v
        if target[i] in trie:
            for v in search_vector(trie[target[i]], target, i-1):
                v.append(target[i])
                yield v

trie = make_trie([
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 0, 2],
    [3, 0, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 3],
])

for v in [
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 4, 2],
    [3, 8, 3, 3],
    [3, 3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4, 4],
]:
    print(v, list(search_vector(trie, v)))
```

Comment: Explain what a trie is (prefix tree) and say that the language is Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed code! I will try this idea.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I think most people can recognize Python, and the word "trie" is easily googleable if people are curious. How it works can be seen by walking through the example by hand. If there are follow-up questions, I can answer them.